# SOLR Query for literal values ignoring case

Tags: solr

I am attempting to index file shares as a way of identifying secrets.  Problem is that most secrets (e.g. P@ssw0rd!) contain special characters that aren't easily escaped. I need a way to search for an exact literal string while ignoring special character meanings.  I'm using SOLR  6.3 and I believe it uses a managed-schema which relies on a REST API to configuration.  I've seen this resolved somewhat with the older schema method, but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want an exact match against the complete value of a field, use a `string` field as that will only give you exact matches without any further processing.

To change a field's type or add a new field with a given type through the Schema API (the managed schema), use [the add field method](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API#SchemaAPI-AddaNewField) with `string` as the field type.

If you're not using a client library, you'll still need to [escape any character with special meaning](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping Special Characters) in Solr (the library will do this for you if you're using SolrJ for example) - this won't give a false positive, but will make certain strings not be able to match the field (if the secret has a space for example).

Comment: I included a string and it seems to be working with test data.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Seems to work except for the "@" symbol.  This isn't listed as a special character and thus doesn't escape when used with a "\".

Comment: Shouldn't be anything special about a @ in a query string. What does your query look like, and what is the content of the _string_ field?

Comment: The query in this instance is "p@ssw0rd" returns results for "password" too.  Not sure on how to give the content, but here's the field that I added. {
        "name":"literal",
        "type":"string",
        "stored":true},

Comment: Did you clean the index (delete the contents) and then reindex after changing the type?

Comment: Be sure that an old document isn't being returned without having been updated / deleted from the index. Also, append `debugQuery=true` to your query to see details about how the query is parsed, and use the `analysis` page if you still get a hit after cleaning your index first.

Comment: Here's a section from the debug, looks like it's stripping the "@" out of the parsedquery. "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"P@ssword",
    "querystring":"P@ssword",
    "parsedquery":"_text_:p _text_:ssword",
    "parsedquery_toString":"_text_:p _text_:ssword",
    "explain":{